# Factoring a matrix

Tags: matrices, factoring

I am attempting to factor the following matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}
  \alpha_1(1-b)-1 & \alpha_2(1-b) & \alpha_3(1-b) \\
  \alpha_1(1-b) & \alpha_2(1-b)-1 & \alpha_3(1-b) \\
  \alpha_1(1-b) & \alpha_2(1-b) & \alpha_3(1-b)-1
\end{bmatrix}

It is obvious that the common factor is $(1 - b)$; however, I am not sure how to deal with the values in the diagonal or even if it is at all possible to factor the matrix.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: you could do $(1-b)A-I$ with $A$ the matrix of all alphas and $I$ the identity matrix.

Comment: Please add it as a solution and I'll mark it as one. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can factor this as $(1-b)A-I$ with $A$ the matrix of alphas and $I$ the identity matrix.